# Firewall problem on Debian 11 while trying to grant access to 443 port

Tags: debian, networking, iptables, firewall

Want to grant access to port 443 for two other computers.
All computers involved have Debian OS.
Ping and traceroute are successful from both IP addresses.
Rules added to iptables:

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.11.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.11.78/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

While using **curl 192.168.11.1:443** from 192.168.11.3 I'm getting:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
 Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
</p>
```

Great, it works!
But when I do the same request from 192.168.11.78 I'm getting this:

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.11.1 port 443 after 129975 ms: Connection timed out
```

iptables on 78 have no rules:

```
iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Please help. I can't find solution. 
Thank you

**EDIT**

I was able to connect using IPv6. Well, I was able to do it from every other IPv6 in my network as well. Learned about **iptables6** in process.
But still can't connect with IPv4 from 78 to 1.

Comment: Are you sure there's no outbound restriction from machine 78?

Comment: `iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT` — everything clear

Comment: can 11.1 ping 11.78

Comment: Does the 11.78 have multiple network interfaces/multiple IP addresses in the 192.168.11.* network? Does it have a firewall that would restrict it from either sending a packet to 11.1's TCP/443, or from receiving the answer?

Comment: Yes, 78 can ping 1 and vice versa. And 78 can access 443 on .1 via IPv6. I suspect that 78 is banned somehow on 1 but can't find where could it be. I'm so desperate that doing **grep -R "192.168.11.78" /**. Nothing came out so far. I'm buffled.

Comment: 11.78 has empty iptables and iptables6

Comment: To tell `curl` to use HTTPS, you would want to connect with `https://` as the default is `http://`. Try running `curl https://192.168.11.1:443`.  The issue between `192.168.11.78` => `192.168.11.1` seems to be a network problem if it took over two minutes to timeout.  If there are any rules above the ACCEPT for the IP address `192.168.11.78`, those might help figure out the problem.